# Why a method without input parameter can be used to replace Function<T,R>

Tags: java, method-reference

For the following code snippet, in `calculateOnShipments`, one parameter accepts a function with `Shipment` as input and `Double` as output.

```
Function<Shipment, Double> f
```

1) Why can it be called using `Shipment::calculateWeight`? `calculateWeight()` does not accept any parameter, although it returns `Double`

```
public double calculateWeight()
```

2) I try to comment out the `calculateWeight()` but keep the `calculateWeight(Shipment s1)`, then there is an error message

> "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method calculateWeight(Shipment) from the type Shipment"

What does this message mean? why it said a static reference? before I comment the `calculateWeight()`, why was there no error message?

```
class Shipment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Shipment> l = new ArrayList<Shipment>();
        l.add(new Shipment());
        l.add(new Shipment());
        Shipment shipment1 = new Shipment();
        // Using an anonymous class
        List<Double> lw = shipment1.calculateOnShipments(l, Shipment::calculateWeight);
        System.out.println(lw);//[0.0,0.0]
    }

    public double calculateWeight() {
        double weight = 0;
        // Calculate weight
        return weight;
    }

    public double calculateWeight(Shipment s1) {
        double weight = 1;
        // Calculate weight
        return weight;
    }

    public List<Double> calculateOnShipments(
            List<Shipment> l, Function<Shipment, Double> f) {
        List<Double> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Shipment s : l) {
            results.add(f.apply(s));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> why it can be called by `Shipment::calculateWeight`? `calculateWeight()`
>   does not accept any parameter, although it return double

It can be called using the method reference since the method reference represent the code to invoke the method `calculateWeight` on a `shipment` which is accepted as an input to the `Function<Shipment, Double>`. Read these for further co-relation --

```
shipment -> shipment.calculateWeight()
```

or further

```
new Function<Shipment, Double>() {
    @Override
    public Double apply(Shipment shipment) {
        return shipment.calculateWeight();
    }
})
```

---

> I try to comment out the calculateWeight() but keep the
>   calculateWeight(Shipment s1), then there is a error msg

Now if you have understood the above lambda representation, the method reference is not possible without the since invoking `calculateWeight` method needs a shipment for one to be *an instance on which the method would be called* and another which would should be *passed to the method to be used as a parameter*. That could be something like --

```
shipment -> shipment.calculateWeight(shipment1)
```

---

Do note, converting the method to be `static` such as

```
public static double calculateWeight(Shipment s1)
```

would result in inferring the method reference to accept the instance as the parameter itself and would work as:

```
List<Double> lw = shipment1.calculateOnShipments(l, Shipment::calculateWeight)
```

where `Shipment::calculateWeight` represents `shipment -> calculateWeight(shipment)`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) By why it can be called by Shipment::calculateWeight? calculateWeight() does not accept any parameter, […]

`calculateWeight()` is a non-static method on class `Shipment`, so in a sense, it takes an implicit `this` parameter of type `Shipment`. So `Shipment::calculateWeight` is a function that takes that one parameter. (If `calculateWeight()` were a non-static method, or if you wrote `shipment1::calculateWeight` rather than `Shipment::calculateWeight` so that the instance is baked into the method reference, then that would be a function with no parameters.)

---

> 2) I try to comment out the calculateWeight() but keep the calculateWeight(Shipment s1), then there is a error msg
>
> > "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method calculateWeight(Shipment) from the type Shipment"
>
> what does this message mean? why it said a static reference? […]

This is a good question. The underlying problem is that, as far as method references are concerned, `calculateWeight(Shipment s1)` takes *two* parameters: the implicit `this` parameter of type `Shipment` (since it's an instance method on class `Shipment`), and the explicit `s1` parameter of type `Shipment`.

The error-message comes out weird; in essence, the compiler is saying "this is not a static method, so you need to give it an instance", the idea being that you could write `shipment1::calculateWeight` rather than `Shipment::calculateWeight` to specify the instance it should be called on.

Comment: any good article or tutorial for method reference suggested? I still do not understand...especially the different between Shipment::calculateWeight and shipment1::caluclateWeight() or in general ClassA::method1 and instanceA::method1
"if you wrote shipment1::calculateWeight rather than Shipment::calculateWeight so that the instance is baked into the method reference, then that would be a function with no parameters.", I cannot understand this statement